# Moving a Berkley Db from XP to Ubuntu

Tags: berkeley-db

I have a bdb database which I have been using on my XP box. I am now migrating most of my apps etc to Linux (Ubuntu 9.10 to be precise).

I am not sure that simply moving the db files will work. Has anyone undergone this process of moving a BDB database from the windows platform to Linux before, and if so what is the procedure?.

Also, during the "migration" is there anything in particular that I need to be aware of (i.e. "gotchas")?

Comment: Is this bdb (c version) or bdb je?

Comment: Step 1: Try it. Step 2. Come back if it doesn't work. :-)

Comment: Theoretically there shouldn't be a problem. I doubt the files are encoded with any platform-specific details.

Comment: Step 1. Backup data, Step 2. Try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, [yes](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=982209&tstart=0), you can migrate the db files between machines/os. The files that bdb creates are cross platform, they only need to be read by bdb which makes this easy.

The [OTN Bdb forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa;jsessionid=8d92079330d60f6f0ecdc857488587f5c65eef0cb49b.e38QbNuQbx8Kbi0LbhaMaxuKbNb0?forumID=271&start=0) is a really good place to ask bdb questions.

Comment: Heheh, that was me asking that question actually. I just wanted to get a second opinion before attempting to migrate several Gbs of data. Also, if there were any issues in moving the db, that would be a show stopper for the entire Windows to Linux migration, since all the applications being migrated, depend on the bdb data store.

Comment: BTW, it is the C/C++ interface to DBD that I am using

Comment: The guys that respond on the OTN are usually well informed, more often than not they are oracle employees or work on bdb. Just back up your data and do what you want to do, it's then trivial to restore and rollback incase there is a problem.